# Warning: require_once(controllers/controller.php)

Tags: php

Cundo lo cargo en el navegador me pone este mensaje:

> Warning: require_once(controllers/controller.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\cursoPHP\03.MVC\index.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'controllers/controller.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\cursoPHP\03.MVC\index.php on line 3

```
<?php
    
require_once "controllers/controller.php";

    $mvc = new MvcController();
    $mvc -> plantilla();

?>
```

Comment: El error indica que no encuentra el archivo controller.php, tienes que escribir de manera correcta la ruta desde index.php hasta donde se encuentra el controlador ej. require_once('../controllers/controller.php').

Comment: actualmente yo tengo un error parecido pero no logro arreglarlo aun, en la pantalla me sale lo siguiente. [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEmHY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEmHY.png)

Comment: Según tu imagen, tu proyecto esta dentro de una carpeta llamada `AplicacionWeb` por lo que el código de tu `require` debería de ser: `require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "AplicacionWeb/regimen/_config.php");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En especifico, el mensaje muestra que el archivo

> "controller.php"

No se encuentra en el directorio

> C:\xampp\htdocs\cursoPHP\03.MVC\controllers\

Como posibles soluciones:

1.- Verifica que los nombres estén escritos correctamente: con mayúsculas y minúsculas.

2.- Que la estructura de tu proyecto sea parecida a:

- cursoPHP

  - 03.MVC

    - controllers

      - controller.php
    - index.php

Answer (score 0):

Me sucedió no se veía la página que quería de mi sistema MVC.Y es que una de las carpetas estaba mal colocada, un ejemplo: de mal ubicada sería que el index estuviera colocado debajo de Páginas, lo correcto sería cortar a index de ahí y llevarla al comienzo, donde está el Controlador, Vista, Modelo. Se debe respetar el orden de ubicación al organizar las carpetas y páginas del sistema.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/401950)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).